# De-serialization of string containing mark-up interface

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I was trying something new to test the serialization of objects using markup interface.

I know in real world this will not be the proper scenario if I follow proper coding standards. But just for the curiosity to learn some work around to achieve the de-serialization of the generated object.

I have following interface and classes:

```
interface intA {}

class classa : intA
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
}

class classb : intA
{
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public int e { get; set; }        
}

class classsd
{
    public List<intA> obj { get; set; }
}
```

I have written following serialization and de-serialization code as follows in main method using 'Newtonsoft.json'.

```
classsd objd = new classsd();

objd.obj = new List<intA>();
objd.obj.Add(new classa() { a = 1, b = 2 });
objd.obj.Add(new classb() { c = "asd", d = "qwe", e = 1 });

var a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objd);

string json = @"{'obj':[{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':'asd','d':'qwe','e':1}]}";

var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<classsd>(a);
```

I get proper serialization string, but when I try to de-serialize, an exception is thrown:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type ConsoleApp1.intA. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.'...

Serialized string is as follows:

```
{'obj': [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 'asd', 'd': 'qwe', 'e': 1 }]}
```

Is there any workaround to achieve this kind of de-serialization?

Comment: Any reason you can't make a class that contains those five properties and use that?

Comment: You need to tell Json.Net to include the type in the serialization, i.e.: new JsonSerializerSettings {  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }.
Otherwise, how would it know which type to deserialize into?
You pass these settings as an argument to both SerializeObject and DeSerializeObject if I recall correctly.

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. Plenty of existing questions already handle this very subject.